# Custom syntax in batch program

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find a way to create custom syntax in my program.

For example, lets say this is the syntax of a command.

/find (object) (number)

If I were to type this:

/find square 2

I want the program to recognize the values i replaced (object) and (number) with and set them as variables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to get each value.

```
@echo off

set /p "command="

for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ("%command%") do (
    set "object=%%b"
    set "number=%%c"
)

echo %object%
echo %number%
pause
```

Example input: `/somecmd foo bar`

Example output:

```
foo
bar
```